# Mail centos 5.5

Tags: php, sendmail, centos5

I have an issue with user on a shared server.

Sent mail bounces are sometimes returned to different users than owners?

I have checked the from and return mail in headers and all fine but still sometimes this issue occures.

Where to look and check?

Answer (score 0):

It could be different depending on what mail server you are using but generally you would look in /var/log/maillog or /var/log/mail.log